# Angular X-Editable Remote button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, inline-editing

I am using Angular X-Editable to allow users to edit list items in a ng-repeat.

I am using this approach: https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#text-btn

However, I have been asked to modify this app so that the user can highlight a row in the repeat by clicking on it and click and edit button elsewhere that would put *whichever row was selected* into x-editable "edit mode".

Looking at their docs I see no method of doing this, nor the event that would put a row into edit mode.  I can get the $index of the row clicked on in my ng-click handler but see no way to put that row into edit mode and capture the edits made.

My ng-repeat is like this so far, which is from the example linked above and shows a "pencil" button for editing that it.  It works fine, but how to have all the items editable from one button on a toolbar or the like?

```
       <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="level1 in pmt..level1 track by $index">

        <button ng-click="textBtnForm.$show()" ng-hide="textBtnForm.$visible">
         <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

        <span editable-text="level1.name" e-form="textBtnForm">
          {{ level1.name || 'empty' }}
        </span>      

        <i class="pull-right fa fa-angle-right fa-lg"></i>
      </div>
```

Note:  I know how to hide the buttons, or use a click on the text.  The question is not eliminating he repeated buttons, but how to have **one** button to edit the focused row.